# jQuery Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery

I've been searching and searching for a reason why this code breaks in IE only.  Seems to work in Firefox and Chrome. IE8 debugger keeps complaining and highlighting this block of code.

```
var query = {
            display: opts.display.join(', '),
            quotes: opts.stocks.map(function (stock) {
                return '"' + stock + '"';
            }).join(', ')
        }
```

Tried even using the jQuery.noConflict, that only made it not work in ANY browser. No specifically calling prototype at all in this project, its just a basic list of stocks symbols and this variable above basically just ties the " and commas between the two according to YQL standard. No idea why this is causing an error.

-update
I've found out why I am getting this error. IE8 and below do not support the javascript map() function. I've read up on example of alternatives and someone suggested using jQuery map function, well that doesn't seem to work either, or I am just not writing it correctly. All attempts are on the var query I am trying to basically recursively go through the array and add the puncuation required for the YQL query.

```
function getStock(opts, complete) {
        var defs = {
            desc: false,
            baseURL: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=',
            query: 'select {display} from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ({quotes}) | sort(field="{sortBy}", descending="{desc}")',
            suffixURL: '&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&format=json&callback=?'
        };
        opts = $.extend({
            display: ['*'],
            stocks: []
        }, opts || {});
        if (!opts.stocks.length) {
            complete('No stock defined');
            return;
        }

        //var query =  $.map({
            //display: opts.display.join(', '),
            //quotes: opts.display.stocks(function(stocks) {
                //return '"' + stocks + '"';
            //}).join(', ')
       // });
        //var query = {
            //display: opts.display.join(', '),
            //quotes : $.map(opts.display.stocks(quotes, function(stock) {
                //return '"' + stock + '"';
            //})).join(', ')
        //};
        alert(query);
        //var query = {
            //display: opts.display.join(', '),
            //quotes: opts.stocks.map(function (stock) {
                //return '"' + stock + '"';
            //}).join(', ')
        //};
        //function (stock) returns "ticker symbol"
        defs.query = defs.query.replace('{display}', query.display).replace('{quotes}', query.quotes).replace('{sortBy}', defs.sortBy).replace('{desc}', defs.desc);
        defs.url = defs.baseURL + defs.query + defs.suffixURL;
        $.getJSON(defs.url, function (data) {
            var err = null;
            if (!data || !data.query) {
                err = true;
            }
            complete(err, !err && data.query.results);
            var items = data.query.results.quote;
            alert(items[0].LastTradePriceOnly);
        });
    }
```

I've included all my failed iterations of this variable alternative.  None of them work in any browser.  Perhaps someone can assist translating this to jQuery equivelant?

Comment: Which line is giving you this error?

Comment: What is `opts.stocks`?

Comment: I'm gonna assume it's the `opts.stocks.map` line.  [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) doesn't exist in IE8.  You need to shim it in: https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Comment: ???  This line isn't even using jQuery!

Comment: you likely need .get() after .map(), if opts.stocks is a jquery object. Otherwise, this has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: so I have found out that IE8 does not support the map() function and that is why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, using the jQuery.com reference to the map function this would be the proper conversion from the previous statement

orginal

```
var query = {
            display: opts.display.join(', '),
            quotes: opts.stocks.map(function (stock) {
                return '"' + stock + '"';
            }).join(', ')
        };
```

jQuery converted

```
var query = {
            display: opts.display.join(', '),
            quotes: $.map(opts.stocks, function (stock) {
                return '"' + stock + '"';
            }).join(', ')
        };
```

end mapping problem for out of date IE browsers